# error working with spring restful service

Tags: spring

i am new to spring restful service and i want to get the result in differnt format when i type the below url-----

```
localhost:7001/SpringRestService/restful/methodName/ALL/ALL/ALL/ALL.xml
localhost:7001/SpringRestService/restful/methodName/ALL/ALL/ALL/ALL.json
localhost:7001/SpringRestService/restful/methodName/ALL/ALL/ALL/ALL.pdf
```

but i am getting the below error when i start my server----

```
 <Servlet: "SpringRest" failed to preload on startup in Web application: "SpringRestService".
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver#0' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/SpringRest-servlet.xml]: Cannot create inner bean 'org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver#20e0f98' of type [org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver] while setting bean property 'viewResolvers' with key [0]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver#20e0f98' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/SpringRest-servlet.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Property 'viewClass' is required
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:282)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:121)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveManagedList(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:353)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:154)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1391)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver#20e0f98' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/SpringRest-servlet.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Property 'viewClass' is required
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:532)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:461)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:271)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:121)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveManagedList(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:353)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Property 'viewClass' is required
```

-----------------------springRest-servlet.xml-----------------------------

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">


<!-- Specify a view resolver for JSP files-->
<bean id="viewResolvers" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"
p:prefix="/WEB-INF/view/" p:suffix=".jsp" />


<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver">
        <property name="mediaTypes">
            <map>
                <entry key="xml" value="application/xml"/>
                <entry key="html" value="text/html"/>
            </map>
        </property>
         <property name="viewResolvers">
    <list>
      <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver"/>
    </list>
  </property>
  <property name="defaultViews">
    <list>
      <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.json.MappingJacksonJsonView" />
    </list>
  </property>
    </bean>   


</beans>

-----------------------------my controller class------------------------------
```

below is my controller class

```
package org.nea.rest.unsr;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;
import org.nea.ia.services.util.uniserv.UniServGrantInfo;
import org.nea.spring.services.interfaces.uniservs.UniservSearchInterface;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

@Controller
public class HelloWorldController1 {
    @Autowired
    UniservSearchInterface uniservService;

    public UniservSearchInterface getUniservService() {
        return uniservService;
    }

    public void setUniservService(UniservSearchInterface uniservService) {
        this.uniservService = uniservService;
    }
    protected final Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(getClass());

    /* commented
    @RequestMapping(value = "/showAllGrants/{userName}/{year}/{status}/{stateId}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody
    List<UniServGrantInfo> getTextFromURL(@PathVariable("userName") String userName, @PathVariable("year") String year,
            @PathVariable("status") String status, @PathVariable("stateId") String stateId) {
        List<UniServGrantInfo> grantInfoList = new ArrayList<UniServGrantInfo>();

        grantInfoList = uniservService.showAllgrants(userName, year, status, stateId);
        return grantInfoList;
    }

    */


    @RequestMapping(value = "/showAllGrants/{userName}/{year}/{status}/{stateId}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView getTextFromURL(@PathVariable("userName") String userName, @PathVariable("year") String year,
            @PathVariable("status") String status, @PathVariable("stateId") String stateId) {
        List<UniServGrantInfo> grantInfoList = new ArrayList<UniServGrantInfo>();

        grantInfoList = uniservService.showAllgrants(userName, year, status, stateId);
        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("index");

        //ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();
       // mav.setViewName("index");
       // mav.addObject("sampleContentList", grantInfoList);
        return model;       
    }



}


can anybody help me telling where i am doing wrong or if i am missing any required jar file.
```

Answer (score 2):

Your configuration for the UrlBasedViewResolver is incomplete. The exception states that the property ‘viewClass‘ is missing. For example a complete configuration:

```
<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
  <property name="prefix" value="/jsp/"/>
  <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
  <property name="viewClass" 
    value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView"/>
</bean>
```